# Composer plugin get list of all packages being removed before removal

Tags: composer-php

I have a Composer plugin that does some of our package asset installations, etc.

I'm adding some logic that occurs on a package uninstall. However, sometimes the plugin itself is removed before other packages that are being installed and need the functionality of the plugin.

Is there a way to get a list of all packages that are goin to be removed before the removals start?

Or, is there a way to force the plugin to be removed last?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do either with a locally installed plugin. For something like this a globally installed plugin might be better, if you need to do "stuff" on uninstall, and the plugin itself is liable to be uninstalled. You can check the list of events [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#package-events), but you are likely already familiar with those.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying not to make a separate installation but it was the only way.